# Batch Generation of Plots with ggplot2/ggseas for different products

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have a tibble data frame for time series analysis. I use the ggseas package for create decomposed seasonal chart. Here is the code for reproducible data.

```
sample_dt <- expand.grid(
Product=c("A","B","C","D"),
Region=c("Asia","Africa","North America","South America","Europe"),
YearMonth=seq.Date(from = as.Date("2012-1-1"),to = as.Date("2016-12-1"),by ="month"))
sample_dt$ActualDemand <- runif(2000,20000,n=1200)
#### arrange for better understanding
sample_dt <- sample_dt%>%
  arrange(Product,Region)
```

and below is the code I use to generate plot for one product, more specifically, product A:

```
sample_dt%>%
  filter(Product=="A")%>%
     ggsdc(aes(x=YearMonth,y=ActualDemand,colour=Region),frequency=12,s.window=7,
     method="stl")+geom_line()+
ggtitle("Time Series for Product A")
```

The problem i have is that i have 1000+ different products, i would like to generate a plot for each product, and save them into the current working directory as a whatever image format available. But i need the title of the plot to change with the product i plotted. i.e. for Product B, the ggtitle should be "Time Series for Product B". Is it possible for R to do this kind of job?
I have also attached a sample plot.
Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean but if you use a loop to plot each product you can simply use paste to create a new title each loop. e.g.:

```
prod = "A"
plotname = paste("Time Series for Product",prod)


sample_dt%>%
 filter(Product=="A")%>%
 ggsdc(aes(x=YearMonth,y=ActualDemand,colour=Region),frequency=12,s.window=7,
 method="stl")+geom_line()+
 ggtitle(plotname)
```

**EDIT** Now including the loop

```
prod_id = c("A","B","C","D")

 for(i in 1:length(prod_id)) {
  plotname = paste("Time Series for Product",prod_id[i])

  p1 = sample_dt%>%
  filter(Product==prod_id[i])%>%
  ggsdc(aes(x=YearMonth,y=ActualDemand,colour=Region),frequency=12,s.window=7,method="stl")+geom_line() + ggtitle(plotname)
  ggsave(paste0(plotname,".jpg"), plot = p1)

}
```

Comment: Hi timfaber, thanks for your help. Actually what i am trying to accomplish is to create separate plots for Product A, B and C, and show the product names in the title of the plots generated and then save each plot into hard drive for further communication with stakeholders.

Comment: Hi timfaber, my problem is solved perfectly with your suggestion. It is amazing, THANKS!

Comment: your code worked very well for me. Just a quick question for you: why do you need to write code:`plotname=plotname` and then fowllowed with paste function. How to understand that?